# $locationChangeStart event hitting twice when changing the location

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am triggering a confirm modal directive popup when the form is dirty and i am changing the location.

```
angular.module("top.app.controllers").directive('confirmOnExit', ['$location', 'ConfirmModal', '$timeout',function (location, ConfirmModal, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', 
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                var unbindChangeSuccess = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current, e) {
                    $scope.DirtyForm = ($scope.componentAddForm.$dirty ? $scope.componentAddForm.$dirty : $scope.resourceForm.$dirty)
                    if ($scope.DirtyForm) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        ConfirmModal.show({
                            okButtonCaption: "OK",
                            cancelButtonCaption: "Cancel",
                            title: "Pending Changes",
                            text: "Any unsaved data to this record will be lost. Click ‘Continue’ to proceed with this action."
                        }).then(function () {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $timeout(function () {
                                window.location = next;
                                $scope.$apply()
                            });
                        })
                    } else {
                    };
                });

            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Do you have a module.config? Please copy it here. Also copy any of the html views that are giving the problem

Comment: What I suspect is that you have a routes definition and also you have put the ng-controller in the view. When you use routes, the controller is solved by the route, so you can omit the ng-controller tag, otherwise the location will be changed twice (route and view)

Comment: I think @zameb is on to something.  Usually when something is getting called twice that is because the controller is being defined twice.  When it was happening to me it was because of the reason that he had mentioned. Would you be able to show us what the html and js code of the route that you are going to?

Comment: i have removed the controller also the issue still persist

Comment: i have used in all the views everywhere its giving same issue.No i dont have any module.config i have bundle.config @zameb